# Is it possible to set PostgreSQL roles with privileges this way?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I'm trying to develop a system, and for the first time I'm using PostgreSQL. I'm trying to organize and separate roles properly, but I'm losing my mind with it (about a week on this now).

Following the title of this question, is it possible to set the following(?):

- A user who can do everything with all tables, **except** perform CRUD
  operations on the records of the same. In addition, this user can not create, delete, modify or insert roles.
- Another user who can perform all CRUD operations on table records,
  but can not perform any structural change operation in database
  objects. This guy cannot create/D/M/I roles as well.
- A third user who behaves like DBA, able to do anything.

The first user serves as a limited DBA who can make structural changes, but can not snoop data. The second is a system using the database. The third and last is a DBA with full control.

This question comes from [another one previously made by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576679/how-to-properly-define-roles-and-privileges-case-study-postgresql), **similar, but not equal.** I do not want to know what's wrong with that code anymore.  Also, I believe that here is the most appropriate place to ask things like that.

I want to know if this is **possible.** If so, I would like to see **how**. If not, I want an explanation of **why**.

Thank you for your attention in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What is possible is what's specified in the documentation for GRANT (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).

To make modifications on tables, a user must own the object. When a user owns an object, a user can do whatever they want with it (including restricting themselves any kind of access, along with the ability to grant themselves any access again).

For your **limited DBA**, there are non-standard ways in which your requirements can be implemented, such as a DBA creating a function with `SECURITY DEFINER` that validates the executing user, and the command to execute, as something allowed, like the following example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION limited_dba_action (p_action text) RETURNS void AS
$body$
BEGIN
  IF p_action !~* '^\s*(CREATE|ALTER)\M' THEN -- add any other valid operations, such as TRUNCATE, DELETE, etc
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Valid operations through this function are limited to creating and altering objects';
  END IF;

  IF p_action ~ ';\s*[^\s]' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Please include only one operation';
  END IF;

  EXECUTE p_action;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION limited_dba_action TO your_limited_dba_user;
```

For your **system using the database**, this is the standard for non-object-owners (i.e. they can do whatever is being granted to them, but not alter/drop the object).

Finally your **DBA** is simply a standard superuser.

So yes, what you require being able to do is perfectly possible.